# How to initialize umbraco MemberService in published model?

Tags: service, model, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 7.6 and ModelsBuilder

I am trying to extend my `CustomMember` model and add some custom properties. I want to get `IMember` as a property. For this I need to initialize `MemberService` to use `GetById()` method.

How to initialize `MemberService` in partial `CustomMember`?

```
public partial class CustomMember 
{
    private readonly MemberService _memberService;

    public CustomMember(IPublishedContent content) : base(content) // this is not valid as the contructor already exists in the umbraco generated partial model
    {
        this._memberService = (MemberService)ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService; // This is coming null
    }

    public IMember Member
    {
        get
        {
            return _memberService.GetById(this.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ApplicationContext.Current.Services` collection to access the MemberService singleton.

https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Management/Services/MemberService/Index

Specifically:

> The MemberService is available through the ApplicationContext, but the if you are using a SurfaceController or the UmbracoUserControl then the MemberService is available through a local Services property.

You should also take a look at this article as well:

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Common-Pitfalls